# Properties of statistical estimators when data is a collection of estimates

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, estimators

Assume I have a statistical estimator $\theta$ that has nice properties (say, unbiased and consistent) when the data $Y=\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\}$ is i.i.d. (possibly with additional assumptions). But now, instead of working with $Y$, I have a collection of estimates $\widehat{Y}=\{\widehat{y}_1,\widehat{y}_2,\dots,\widehat{y}_n\}$ and I would like to know whether $\theta$ has the same nice properties.

1. Is it possible to say anything about $\theta|\widehat{Y}$?
2. What would I need to assume about $\widehat{y}_i$? (Say, each $y_i$ is the true parameter of a local parametric model and I am estimating $\widehat{y}_i$ from local data $X_i$)
3. Which literature should I read to learn more?

Motivation: Essentially, I want to do a two-level estimation. I start with a collection of datasets $\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ from which I estimate a collection of parameter vectors $\widehat{Y}=\{\widehat{y}_1,\widehat{y}_2,\dots,\widehat{y}_n\}$ (for example, coefficients in the OLS estimation). And then I want to find an estimate from $\widehat{Y}$ (in the specific case I am thinking now, I am interested in the clustering of $\widehat{Y}$ but it can be something more general. Just using $\widehat{Y}$ as a collection of observations as an input to another estimation problem.)

Comment: What is $X? $ How is related with $Y? $ What are you trying to find condoning $\theta$ (the usage of $\theta$ as estimator is quite unusual)? I think there maybe a genuine query underlying the post but is befuddled with unusual notations. Clarity is warranted.

Comment: @User1865345 X was a typo, my apologies. I fixed that and added context

Comment: You could look into multilevel models, search this site. The question is still very general, so please specify more your models. Since you want to look into the clustering (maybe spread?) Of estimates, maybe a mixed model. Andrew Gelman (search his blog) calls what you are doing "the secret weapon"

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you! To be honest, at the moment, I just want to understand the landscape of what's done and known at least on some elementary level. And since I didn't know the correct keywords my search wasn't productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Partial answer, but too long for a comment]

This situation is very common in experimental psychology and cognitive neuroscience, where you often have multiple research participants completing multiple trials in an experiment or repetitions of the same stimulus in neuroimaging. $\hat Y$ might be simple averages (e.g. average response times in different conditions) or estimates from more complex models (e.g. drift diffusion models fit to a single participant's response times, reinforcement learning models fit to their choices, a GLM fit to neural data). More often than not, these "level 1 estimates" are fed into a "level 2" t-test, ANOVA, or regression analysis.

A commonly-cited limitation of this approach is that it ignores uncertainty in the individual $\hat Y$ estimates, rather than giving less weighting to more uncertain estimates. For this reason, multilevel models are increasingly used instead, where this weighting occurs automatically. [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022249621000742) is a good starting point for reading about this approach as applied to RL models.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful